# Best way to complete all equations for array in python, problem with bounds and axis size for user inputs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I defined a function to create an array from user input list of wavelengths in my GUI. Right now it is set for three inputs for two arrays but really I would like to code this for any number of wavelengths or exposures.

The function needs to take the difference between the first input and calibrated home wavelength and then tell the user that difference and translate it to mechanical steps for serial movement, move then take an exposure(moving and exposure not implemented yet). Then, for the rest of the array, the code needs to take the difference between the next input and the previous input in the list, then again tell the user that difference and translate it to mechanical steps for serial movement,move and take an exposure.

The issue here is that list is only so long, and the code is throwing an error for the last input in the list. What can I change to allow this code to run? I have tried difference_wave=np.roll(wavelist,-1)-wavelist but it throws a different error, which I included below my code:

```
def scanadv():
wavelist = np.array([input("Enter wavelength you want to scan to: ") for wave in range(3)])
    exposure = np.array([input("Enter exposure time for each wavelength: ") for exp in range(3)])
    home = 631.26 #nm
    rev = 9000 #steps = 1 nm
    for idx,wave in enumerate(wavelist):  
        if idx == 0:
            currentwave = home
            diff_wave = float(wavelist[0])-currentwave
            diff_step = diff_wave*rev
            print(f"Moving scan controller {diff_wave}nm to {wavelist[0]}nm")
            print(f"Hold for current exposure {exposure[idx]} seconds")
            print(f"The exposure for {wavelist[0]}nm was taken")
            currentwave = wavelist[idx+1]
        else:
            for wave in range(1):
                diff_wave = float(currentwave)-float(wavelist[idx+1])     
                print(f"Moving to {currentwave}nm now")
                #move command
                #check or wait to reach next wavelength
                print(f"Hold for current exposure {exposure[idx]} seconds")
                #take exposure/hold time for exposure
                print(f"The exposure for {currentwave}nm was taken")
                #update
                currentwave = wavelist[idx+1]
```

**Error**

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-c08a101581a4> in <module>
----> 1 scanadv()

<ipython-input-100-9923a5353f95> in scanadv()
     18         else:
     19             for wave in range(1):
---> 20                 diff_wave = float(currentwave)-float(wavelist[idx+1])
     21                 print(f"Moving to {currentwave}nm now")
     22                 #move command

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

**Error from trying diff_wave = np.roll(wavelist,-1)-wavelist**

```
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-c08a101581a4> in <module>
----> 1 scanadv()

<ipython-input-102-3430ddd9dbe4> in scanadv()
      7     home = 631.26 #nm
      8     rev = 9000 #steps = 1 nm
----> 9     diff_wave = np.roll(wavelist,-1)-wavelist
     10     diff_step = rev*diff_wave[:-1]
     11     for idx,wave in enumerate(wavelist):

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U3'), dtype('<U3')) -> dtype('<U3')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to take the differences `wavelist[1] - wavelist[2]` , `[2] - [3]` and so on?
If so, what do you want to do with the last one?
You can ignore it and not take that difference by change the `else` to an 
`elif idx < len(wavelist) - 1` 
so there is no case where `idx + 1` exceeds `len(wavelist) - 1`, the maximum index present in the `wavelist`

Note that the final wavelength `waveleist[len(wavelist)-1]` (or `wavelist[-1]` for short) **will be included** in the last iteration(for `idx = len(wavelist)-2`), which will compute the difference
`[len - 2] - [len - 1]`, 
since the formula is `[idx] - [idx+1]`
(assume `len` to be short `len(wavelist)`)

Comment: For now doing [1]-[2] and [2]-[3] would work, but I would want the final array to be any number of wavelengths, not just three wavelengths. The last wavelength does need to be scanned and moved to as well, the ```elif idx < len(wavelist) - 1``` would not work for this case as I want the final wavelength to be included.

Comment: I just meant that as an example, of course you're iterating over all the rest elements. 
Also, i edited my answer